# Notepad ++ How to replace a whole line that starts with a given expression

Tags: notepad++, notepad

I have a notepad file that contains the following string ") ON [SQLTest" at the beginning of some lines.
How to find every occurrence of that string in notepad++ and replace the whole line with this new string ") ON [PRIMARY]"

Comment: What is a `notepad file`?

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ is very good at this kind of task.  It has a Search and Replace feature which lets you specify a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (also known as "RegEx") for the text to find and its replacement.

You can access it from the Search menu or by pressing Ctrl+H.

In your case, the text to find is:

```
^\) ON \[SQLTest.*
```

and its replacement is

```
\) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Round and square brackets have significance in regular expressions, so I "escaped" them by preceding them with a backslash.

The caret symbol means "start of line" and `.*` matches all characters (if there are any) until the end of the line.

[image: Screenshot of the "Replace" dialog]

Note: if you want to retain the text after "SQLTest" you can capture it by enclosing `.*` in parentheses then refer to it as `\1` in the replacement expression.

Searching for "online regex tester" will reveal many sites where you can experiment to get your expression right.

Comment: The question asks for *"... and replace the whole line with ..."*. Hence there is no need for the capture group, just need a final `.*` (without the preceding space), also do not need the  `\1` in the replace.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianHHH I have updated my answer as suggested.